# Jenkins pipeline checking out to new workspace when previous build has been aborted

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running into a weirdly specific issue, I have a Jenkins Declarative Pipeline (from an SVN hosted Jenkinsfile) that is configured to not run concurrent builds and abort previous builds when a new build is triggered.

Current builds are being aborted correctly however the problem I am running into is that Jenkins will re-checkout the whole repository to an @2 suffixed workspace directory for the subsequent build, this ONLY happens when a build is aborted by Jenkins (Due to the aforementioned "Do not allow concurrent builds" and "Abort previous builds" pipeline configuration) after a new build is triggered VIA SCM polling, oddly if the first build is left to end, it re-uses the same directory.

I've seen a ton of threads stating that this is by design, but from what I can see that's only when concurrent builds are enabled, but since it's not I'm confused as to what could cause Jenkins to not re-use the same workspace directory?

If the "why" I require this is necessary, I have a few large repositories (for Unreal Engine games specifically), that I need to build and as an optimization measure for the time in compiling, cooking and uploading the game, it makes perfect sense to cancel old builds but instead Jenkins decides to clean checkout 10+GB of game code and assets (20+ in the case of some other games) in another folder becuase it can't reuse a folder that's not having a job/build executed in it already .

Happy to accept all possible solutions/suggestions as I'm getting a lil' tired of pulling my hair out.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xK1VEyHX8SDKLEaJMnYAC2mN1cllXA3L) is a link to my Jenkinsfile and groovy script that I've been using, I have removed the meat of the code (due to sensitive info), but the agent, envirnoment, node, stages and steps are all there.

Comment: I know what you’re referring to and I believe I know why but regardless can you post your Jenkinsfile and screenshots of the workspace directories

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli Sure thing, [HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rLjgDHDp_0HTYRhafbnrIcQaZUqmjWVg/view?usp=drivesdk) is a link to the Pipeline Library I wrote for all my projects, [HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jE7r5o7M0nqE_KhI6lgqdgw_FXsUBjEh/view?usp=drivesdk) is a link to the Jenkinsfile for a project and regarding the workspace directories they're basically just the root of the game repo, nothing fancy. [HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1makwAhqi7cqpR_Or0PwvssqYA7jO6ruA/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli Appologies for the pinging you again, but do you happen to have any idea what's causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with my pipeline. I tried deleting the aborted builds and restarted jenkins. I also deleted the @2 directories in my workspace and only kept the main directory out there. Post this,I didn't face the same issue. This could happen because of the jenkins cache. Make sure that your workspace is correctly reflecting the directory name mentioned in your jenkins  file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll give it a go!

I have a feeling it's that Jenkins doesn't unlock the workspace for aborted builds correctly, if your suggestion doesn't remedy the issue what I might just do is have the pipeline script refer to the repository outside of the workspace and issue SCM commands to update, etc via the pipeline script, that way the workspace folder itself doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in the library that you're calling it would be like this

```
def call() {
  node {
    <some code here>
  }
}
```

and in this case the method you're calling will run in a different workspace @2 or @3 depending on the number of calls you're doing and to run in the same workspace you simply need to remove the node part from your library to be like this

```
def call() {
  <write your code directly here!>
}
```

but you need to understand that you're now writing in the stage calling this method and all you're writing here would be in the same stage and you can't split it to stages within the called method

Comment: Hiya, thanks for your response, I actually have my entire pipeline within the library itself and I only call the library once, the problem is that entirely separate builds trigger in different workspaces even with "Abort previous builds" under the job configuration menu checked.

[Here's](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xK1VEyHX8SDKLEaJMnYAC2mN1cllXA3L) a link to the files on my Google Drive, I have removed the meat of the script (due to sensitive info), but the agent, envirnoment, node, stages and steps are all there.